# Difference between Aut(V) and GL(V)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In some texts they treat them as the same but in others they seem they would not necessarily be the same. Please correct me in the following.

1) Let V be a vector space of finite dimension n on a field F (not necessarily the real numbers or complex numbers), then Aut(V) = GL(V) (not just isomorphic but equal to each other).

2) What if V has infinite dimension on a field F, is there a difference between Aut(V) and GL(V)?

I had this question because for example, if A is a finite-dimensional non-associative algebra over F, the book i am reading just states Aut(A) as a subgroup of GL(A) (screenshot is attached below). They use this fact in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363935/automorphism-group-of-a-lie-algebra-as-a-lie-subgroup-of-gl-frak-g) too. I don't think they are referring to a trivial subgroup, so I guess they are not equal to each other for some situations.

If GL(V) and Aut(V) are not always the same, could you please state a generalized concept for each of those groups?
Thanks in avance!

[image: book]

Comment: You are mixing up algebraic structures.  The passage you quote concerns non-associative algebras.  Not all linear maps on the underlying vector space will preserve the binary product.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\text{GL}(A)$ is the set of isomorphism $f : A \to A$ where $A$ is considered as a vector space over $K$. $\text{Aut}(A)$ is the set of *$K$-algebra* automorphism $f : A \to A$, i.e elements of $\text{GL}(A)$ which satisfy in addition the property that $f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$. So indeed for an algebra one has $\text{Aut}(A) \subset \text{GL}(A)$.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to find a difference in the wrong spot. So there is no difference between GL(V) and Aut(V) when V is an arbitrary vector space right?

Comment: For a simple concrete example, regard $\Bbb C$ as an $\Bbb R$-algebra. Then, the general linear group of $\Bbb C$ as a ($2$-dimensional) vector space over $\Bbb R$ is $\textrm{GL}(\Bbb C) \cong \textrm{GL}(2, \Bbb R)$. By contrast $\textrm{Aut}(\Bbb C)$, the group of $\Bbb R$-algebra automorphisms $\Bbb C \to \Bbb C$, is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2$; the nonidentity element is the complex conjugation map.

Comment: @Cami77 : exactly yes !

Comment: Dear @Cami77 if this answer was useful for you, you can accept it by clicking on the little green mark next to the question :)

Comment: Thought I did that, thanks for the help!